# monerod can't synchronize

Tags: monerod

when running monerod I keep getting an error

```
2017-03-29 20:07:11.704 [P2P9]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3339 Block with id: <db7b9b1d3b1bddfa8dba171afbc2f91346a90f25335c09f00e0ca090b5544056> has incorrect miner transaction
```

It's now stuck on height 1274863 and can't sync above that.
Anyone knows what may be the problem?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: latest - v0.10.3.1

Comment: Same issue as reported [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/61yy9s/essential_update_monero_01031_wolfram_warptangent/dfk2nvt/?context=3). Make sure to read the full comment chain. In addition, the solution is posted in the comment chain as well.

Comment: using `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 1000` solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Jona - can you please write your comment with the fix as an answer to this question, and then accept it?

Comment: @bigreddmachine sure thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing some of the last blocks using

```
./monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 1000
```

fixed the problem